# Command routing for Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, routed-commands, icommand

*Basically I want to create a keyboard shortcut which is valid within the scope of a window, and not just enabled when focus is within the control that binds it.*

in more detail....

I have a window which has 3 controls:

- a toolbar
- a textbox
- a Custom Control

The toolbar has a button bound to the Command `CustomCommands.CmdA`, and linked to keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

My Custom Control can process `CmdA`. When I run the app and click on my custom control `CmdA` is enabled and works fine. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> causes the command to fire.

However when I select the text box, my custom command `CmdA` becomes disabled.

I can rectify this by setting the command target for `CmdA`'s button. Now when I select the textBox, `CmdA` is still enabled.

But the Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does nothing.

Is there any easy way to change the scope of keyboard shortcuts? Or do I need to catch the keypress somewhere lower down, and work out which Command it relates to and route it myself (if so is there a framework within which to do this?)

Answer (score 2):

For that you normally just need to specify the input bindings in the window, e.g.:

```
 <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Control" Command="New"/>
        ...
 </Window.InputBindings>
```

For built-in application commands (which are `RoutedCommands`) you need `CommandBinding` in the window as well.

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="New" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
        ...
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: Thanks H.B, but this would bind the "new" command to the "CommandBinding_Executed" function implmented in the Window's code behind. 

However, the user control needs to handle it.

This is more of an issue as the user control is created dynamically, and I don't know which of a 100 or so custom commands it will be able to handle.